# Delphi and Excel.FormatConditions

Tags: excel, delphi, automation, delphi-xe2

I am having problems setting up Conditional Formatting from Delphi XE2 using Early binding with Excel 2010

The Macro I am trying to reproduce is as follows:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
    Formula1:="=6"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Try as I might I cannot seem to access the equivalent of `Selction.FormatConditions(1)` to work

The closest I have reached is with the following code:

```
XR := Xlapp.Range(...) 
XR.FormatConditions.Delete;
XR.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, '=6', EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
```

Which works. When I try and define the colours I have problems

```
FC := XR.FormatConditions[1];
FC.SetFirstPriority;
with FC.Interior do
begin
   PatternColorIndex := xlAutomatic;
   ThemeColor := xlThemeColorAccent6;
end;
```

However this keeps telling me that XR.FormatConditions(1) is and IDispatch and thus incompatible with the FormatCondition assignment

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you make it clear what the error is. Runtime or compile time? Which line. And what is the precise error message. Use copy/paste to give us that. Select the text of the message and then press CTRL and C together. That copies it to the clipboard. Then edit the question and press CTRL and V together. That pastes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Selection` as an `ExcelRange`. Excel XP also requires the second and third parameter to be `OleVariant`, so this should work (it compiles, anyway):

```
var
  Sel: ExcelRange;
  Op, Formula: OleVariant;
  Condition: FormatCondition;
begin
  Sel := ExcelApplication1.Selection[1] as ExcelRange;
  Op := xlGreater;
  Formula := '=6';
  Sel.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, Op, Formula, EmptyParam);
  Condition := Sel.FormatConditions[1] as FormatCondition;
  Condition.Interior.PatternColorIndex := xlAutomatic;
  // Do whatever else
end;
```

Comment: XR is an ExcelRange. The .Add compiles, it's the nextblinesvthatvareva problem.

Comment: I thought you could extrapolate from the `as ExcelRange` example. I've added another one with `Sel.FormatConditions[0] as FormatCondition;`. It's the same concept - retrieve the actual interface needed by using the `as` operator on an `IDispatch`.

Comment: I missed the "as" in your example.  Forcing the cast does what I need

Comment: Just to clarify, Dan: That isn't "forcing the cast". It's the proper way to request an actual interface from an IDispatch - Delphi allows that syntax, but the compiler is actually using `QueryInterface` behind the scenes to ask for the desired interface, and if it's not available you won't get one back. It's not like typecasting. :-)

Comment: I had to use Sel.FormatConditions[1] as the index was not zero based